# .htaccess 5000 redirects with no pattern

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi Im sorry if this is a vague question but all the solutions I find seem to assume there is a pattern when doing 1000s of redirects.

My issue is that we inherited a new website and were asked to make it live, host it and basically be the guys working on it from now on, they werent happy with the developers that built the new site.

The old site is a totally different platform to the new one and basically even though there is a vague pattern in terms of products, categories, etc, really I dont see anything that I could solidly work as a shortcut without losing lots of direct redirects of products.

Some products have more words in the new urls than the old ones, categories have been moved around and recategorized etc.

What is the standard practice when the sitemap has this many urls (approx 5000)?

Interestingly enough , i googled the site using site:www.example.com and 32 pages showed up, so I was tempted to simply do the redirects for these and leave the rest. Is this is a big no no?

Comment: I understand the URLs aren't in any pattern. Will you be able to prepare a list of this 5000 urls somehow and save it in a database along with their new URLs?

Comment: Well I have a list prepared for the old URLs alright, but not the new ones unfortunately.